# Upgrading from AngularJS1.2 to Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am currently working in AngularJS 1.2 application, it is a medium size application with 25 modules, now I want to upgrade to angular new version. I can't write freshly because it is an old project, I don't know older requirements of this project. Please any one suggest me the best way to achieve it.

Comment: Simple answer.... You can't. You have to start freshly, As AngularJS1.2 and Angular are completely different from each other

Comment: You can but this is based on angular 2.0 so then you have to upgrade from 2.0 to 8.0
https://angular.io/guide/upgrade. it will be alot of work and there are a few guides on it. It can be that you need to recreate 20% of your application in Angular. DO your `resourch` and make an estimation of time spend on it.

Answer (score 0):

Its not that easy to convert a angular-1 project to Angular-2+. You must need a fresh start, because both the framework is totally different. For project requirement/ business logic, you must understand the logic and the code and then write a fresh code in Angular-2+.

You may copy and paste any javascript code from angular-1 to angular-2+. It will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

This page helped me a lot when I upgraded to angular: https://angular.io/guide/upgrade
A very good handbook for upgrading to angular is: https://angular.io/guide/ajs-quick-reference

A good solution would be to use ngUpgrade: run both AngularJS and Angular at the same time. All Angular code is running in the Angular framework, and AngularJS code in the AngularJS framework.
What happens on top of this is that components and services managed by one framework can interoperate with those from the other framework. This happens in three main areas: Dependency injection, the DOM, and change detection.

Some main things to take into consideration when upgrading:
- Get AngularJS and Angular components and services talking to each other during the upgrade
- Replacing controllers
- Replacing $scope and $watch
- convert directives to components